PowerApps - Multi Screen/Form App connected to SharePoint Lists - Repopulating multiple attachments
I have a custom SharePoint form in PowerApps in which I'm submitting data to one item from several different screens.  One screen however contains 3 additional forms so that I can leverage their Attachment fields.  I have the user successfully submitting all three forms with their attachments to those lists, but can't get them to re-populate when this item is re-opened.  Each of these three forms reverts back to "New" after submitting.  The user populates information on Screen 1, then Submits (which creates the item in SP).  Then they move to the 2nd screen, populate more data, click "Save" (which updates that item in SP).  So the 3rd screen's forms don't submit to that same list, rather 3 different lists so that they can add most attachments.  So when the user is at this 3rd screen, I want them to "Save" (create items in those 3 lists), and have the ability to close the entire App to complete the rest of the data later.  Once the user has submitted all of this at this point, and they re-open that App, those 3 Attachment forms are blank because the App reset those forms to "New".
I hope I explained that well enough.
Thanks!
